# iPhone - Propose the user to connect to a wifi access point

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, connection, settings, wifi

Into my application, how can I propose my user to connect to a wifi access point, with one of those prefered options, not regarding the current connection type :

1) connect to a named access point (not possible on my knowledge)
2) display the Wifi access point dialog so the user can select and connect to the wanted wifi access point
3) any other user-friendly option, that does not leave the user do everything by itself

without using any private API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access a list of wifi points, or bring up any dialog for the user to connect to a wifi point. All wifi functionality is not exposed as a public API. Real wifi scanners were banned by Apple in 2010. The user has to do everything by himself, which makes sense for security reasons.

If you still want any of that you have to use the private framework MobileWiFi.framework which replaced the old Apple80211.framework.